# How do I write a conditional http.get to create a record if it's null angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, service

I am curious to how I would add a conditional statement in a http.get service call.

For instance my service call:

```
$http.get(baseURL + "/api/complaints/" + $scope.Case + "/clists")
    .then(function (cl) {
        //success
        $scope.cl = []
        $scope.cl = cl;

    }, function (err) {
        //failure
        var errorMessage = "Cannot post checklists" + err;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        var isBusy = false;
    });
```

I want to add a conditional to say if, the clists doesn't exist for $scope.Case, please run the post service call to create a clist. Something that looks like this:

```
$http.get(baseURL + "/api/complaints/" + $scope.Case + "/clists"")
    .then(function (cl) {
        //success
        $scope.cl = []
        if ($scope.cl.ID == null) {
            $http.post(baseURL + "/api/complaints/" + $scope.Case + "/clists")
            $scope.cl = cl;
        }
        else {
            $scope.cl = cl;
        }
    }, function (err) {
        //failure
        var errorMessage = "Cannot post checklists" + err;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        var isBusy = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine except for this part.  You need to add a callback function for the post's promise:

```
if ($scope.cl.ID == null) {
    $http.post(baseURL + "/api/complaints/" + $scope.Case + "/clists")
        .then(function(cl) { 
            $scope.cl = cl;
        }
}
```